# How to publish output from artifactreport task when publishing to an ivy reposiotry

Tags: ant, ivy

I am using ivy with ant to build multiple modules. I need a xml document that specifies all the dependencies along with their version number for each module. I found artifactreport task is what I am looking for but I am not sure how I can publish this along with my artifacts (.jars and .wars) when I build the modules and publish it to my shared ivy repository. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps publishing the HTML output of the ivy report task would be more useful?

Comment: Actually I want an XML file, as a website need to parse it. So, what I was thinking is to run artifactreport task before publishing and use this xml report has one of the publication artifact. Do you see any issue there?

Comment: I see no issue. Just include the XML file in the list of published artifacts in your ivy file. Should work fine.